# Add CMakeLists.txt pattern to Ctags langmap

Tags: exuberant-ctags

At the documentation I saw we could add literal filename (no-extension) support to `ctags --langmap` but I failed to introduce CMakeLists.txt. How to add CMakeLists.txt as well as .cmake extension?

Please find my definition at: https://github.com/umitkablan/vims/commit/33aaac8312774913b911984158d6a000362c57bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was seeking through other's ctags configurations, I came across https://gist.github.com/romainl/085b4db4a26a06ec7e16#file-ctags-L43 and the line `--langmap=vim:+(vimrc)` gave me an idea about how to add literal names.
So I applied similar approach:

```
..
--langdef=cmake
--langmap=cmake:(CMakeLists.txt)
--langmap=cmake:+.cmake
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal-ctags (https://ctags.io) has built-in cmake parser.
If you use it, you don't have to define your own one.